# Publication fee will not be paid at deadline – what will happen and how should I proceed?

Tags: publications, fees

My team's article was published online 2018, with me as the lead author and corresponding author. The print publication followed in early 2019. Shortly thereafter I received the bill for the publication fees. These should be paid by the institution where the working group is located (I am now working elsewhere). This was assured to me by my supervisor. I forwarded the mail with the invoice to him and was again promised that he would take care of the payment. As I learned a few weeks later, the head of the institution refused to pay, as there were currently no funds available. Last week I learned that such bills are not being paid at the moment, as the budget of the institution has not yet been released. The bill is due next week.

1. What does usually happen if such a bill is not paid on time?
2. Is my publication in danger?
3. Should I contact the publisher and inform them about the situation and ask for a respite?

Comment: 1. We can't know. 2. We can't know. 3. Yes.

Comment: @corey979 This is surely nothing that happens only to me, so it would be helpful to learn how publishers in general handle such problems.

Comment: So, contact the publishers... Why do you think we can answer?

Comment: @corey979 I changed the first question.

Comment: They can dump your paper (unlikely) or give you an extension to pay the fee (likely)

Comment: @SolarMike I have no idea, why people are so unfriendly here. The questions are quite clear: What does usually happen? Are papers retracted for this reason? What is your experience/opinion on contacting the publisher in such a case.

Comment: You post a question that can only be answered by contacting the relevant publisher about your specific paper expecting us to know what will happen, without giving us the title or anything, then moan that we cannot help. The first comment answered your 3 questions, which by the way, should have been only one, if you had read about what and how to post.... If publishers have put in the work to prepare your paper for publication, then they should be paid for that work... They will probably, organise an extension to the payment date... **BUT** YOU have to contact them and talk to them, we can't...

Comment: Not unfriendly. This issue depends on the publishers, journals, maybe also editors... There will be as many stories and opinions as journals and people that published. What if a few persons share their experience as "nothing will happen, you'll pay later and nothing will happen" (this is one personal experience from me, too), but in your particular case your paper gets dumped immediately after the deadline? You'll come back and complain "you guys said nothing will happen!"? We don't know what will happen, only your publisher can answer your question. Ask them.

Comment: @corey979 This would have been a suitable answer for me. Obviously, I can't give the title of the paper (@Solar Mike) or expose the whole situation which extends beyond my person (colleagues, supervisor, institution). It wasn't clear to me that contacting the journal is obviously a good idea, so I asked here. I read quite a few posts and answers here and they were often on if and how to contact someone in academia.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely contact the publisher about this. This is a publisher-level question, and likely not something the editorial board will be able to handle.

The good news is that the publisher is almost as interested as you are in getting the paper published. They (or the editorial board) have already put in the effort to get it peer reviewed, and from your description, they've likely also put in the effort to copyedit/typeset/get a DOI/etc. They have little to gain by not publishing the paper, and while putting a paper online for free is not ideal, there's something to be said for building goodwill as well.

I suspect the most likely result is that they'll hold off on Open Access. In other words, your paper will be available to subscribers only. If this isn't possible (the journal is open access only), they might delay publication until the payment is received. If the payment is never going to come, they might publish anyway but hold on to the copyright (free access, not open access), or provide a heavy discount or even just give free OA. For example, if the editorial board tells the publisher your paper is really good, they might be more inclined to give free OA.